# finding common elements between two list using lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have following two list:

```
var firstList = new List<ProgramInfo> ()
{
    new ProgramInfo {Name = "A", ProgramId = 1, Description = "some text1"},
    new ProgramInfo {Name = "C", ProgramId = 2, Description = "some text2"},
    new ProgramInfo {Name = "D", ProgramId = 3, Description = "some text3"},
    new ProgramInfo {Name = "E", ProgramId = 4, Description = "some text4"}
};

var secondList = new List<ProgramInfo> ()
{
    new ProgramInfo {Name = "C", ProgramId = 2, Description = "some text1"},
    new ProgramInfo {Name = "D", ProgramId = 3, Description = "some text2"},
};
```

this two list gets generated at runtime and I have to select the common ProgramInfo depending on the program id from both of this list

for example, in case of above example the output should be

```
var thirdList = new List<ProgramInfo>()
{
    new ProgramInfo {Name = "C", ProgramId = 2, Description = "some text1"},
    new ProgramInfo {Name = "D", ProgramId = 3, Description = "some text2"},
};

  public class ProgramInfo
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ProgramId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
  }
```

Can someone suggest me how can I do this using lambda expression?

Comment: It might be a typo but not sure - I the `secondList` and `thirdList` did you mean `"some text2"` and `"some text3"` like in the lists above?

Comment: Not sure i see much research effort here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Linq `.Intersect`. For that to work your class needs to override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode`

```
var thirdList = firstList.Intersect(secondList);
```

You can also specify an `IEqualityComparer` instead of overriding the functions:

```
public class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<ProgramInfo>
{
   public bool Equals(ProgramInfo x, ProgramInfo y)
   {
      return x.Name == y.Name &&
             x.ProgramId == y.ProgramId &&
             x.Description == y.Description;
   }

   public int GetHashCode(ProgramInfo obj)
   {
      return obj.Name.GetHashCode() ^
             obj.ProgramId.GetHashCode() ^
             obj.Description.GetHashCode();
   }
}

var thirdList = firstList.Intersect(secondList, new Comparer());
```

Comment: @App - Cool :) if you found this helpful please consider marking as solved and upvoting :)